# Change iframe style on second load, doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to change the style of an iframe on the second load. I tried this:

```js
$(function() {
    var loadCnt = 0;

    $('#iframem').load(function() {
        if (loadCnt >0) {
            $("#idiv").width(453).height(349);
            $("#iframem").css("left", "-656px");
            $("#iframem").css("top", "-250px");
        }
        ++loadCnt;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 377px; height: 230px; position: relative;" id="idiv">
<iframe  id="iframem" src="http://www.example.org" style="border: 0pt none ; left: -1px; top: -8px; position: absolute; width: 1680px; height: 867px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

It works perfectly, but it is not working on Internet Explorer 9. What is the correct approach to do that?

Comment: which version of IE?

Comment: IE 9...................

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a logical problem in your approach and am not sure how you have it working at all. As JavaScript only runs after the page loads, this mean that in your code you would never actually get to `loadCnt` larger than 1 - as every time you load the page it sets it to 0 again.

In order to achieve what you are describing you will need to take a different approach, and there are several ways to go about it:

1. Use a server-side language and use a session variable where you set
   the load count
2. If your pages are loaded through [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and injected to the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), then, for example, if your code is on the home page on the first 'real'
   load of the page the `loadCnt` and then moving between pages when
   you 'load' the homepage again you actally are not loading the whole
   JavaScript script, just re-injecting the HTML to the document and then you can add a listener that uses the `loadCnt`.
3. Use JavaScript localStorage - on the first load you will set the
   counter to 0 on a local storage object that you will be able to
   retrieve on later loads:

   ```
   if (localStorage.getItem("counter") === null) {
       // Check if the item exists; if not set it to 0 as it is the first run
       localStorage.setItem('counter', 0);
   }
   else {
       // Get the counter - here you can do your work for when the page is loaded after the first load
       localStorage.getItem('counter');
   }
   ```
4. Use a Javascript cookie to do the same as in previous logic, but in a cookie (as localStorage could have compatibility issues)

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the `onload` attribute to set any function. In Internet Explorer you can't set the `onload` event by code. There is the way to do it, I mentioned in option 2 of my answer.

***Option 1***

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 377px; height: 230px; position: relative;" id="idiv">
    <iframe  id="iframem" src="http://www.example.com" style="border: 0pt none ; left: -1px; top: -8px; position: absolute; width: 1680px; height: 867px;" scrolling="no" onload="myIframeLoadFunction()">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var loadCnt = 0;
function myIframeLoadFunction(){
    if (loadCnt >0) {
        $("#idiv").width(453).height(349);
        $("#iframem").css("left", "-656px");
        $("#iframem").css("top", "-250px");
    }
    ++loadCnt;
}
```

***Option 2***

You need to specifically bind onload event after element gets render on HTML.

**JavaScript Code**

```
(function (selector) {
    var loadCnt = 0, frame = $(selector).get(0);
    if (frame) {
        frame.onload = function () {
            if (loadCnt >0) {
              $("#idiv").width(453).height(349);
              $("#iframem").css("left", "-656px");
              $("#iframem").css("top", "-250px");
            }
            ++loadCnt;
        };
    }
})('#iframem');
```